# mySQL column that is auto incremented every for every duplicate?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

Let's say I have a table of objects with the following characteristics :

`- name`
`- count`

Name is the primary key.

Sample data :

```
Shoes - 1
Pants - 1
```

Is it possible to increment an object's count every time an object with the same primary key is added to the table?

For example if I were to add an object with the name of Shoe, the table would show:

```
 Shoes - 2
 Pants - 1
```

Comment: If you want to show data in this format just look for the count and group by query this will do the job instead of finding a complex procedure or triggers

Comment: The 'same' primary key? Eh? If it's the same, then it ain't primary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), which performs an update instead of insert if the name you are attempting to insert already exists :

```
INSERT INTO tablename (name,count) VALUES ('Shoes',1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1;
```